# C# Consuming API that throws HTTPError doesn't deserialize the error

Tags: c#, winapi, asp.net-web-api

Thank you in advance for the help:

My situation is this: 
I have an API that, when the server errors, returns a content of System.Web.Http.HttpError.

```
var errorResponse = new ErrorResponseFactory(ex, _showDebug);
System.Web.Http.HttpError error = errorResponse.Error;
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
```

When doing unit testing - calling the API method directly, I can extract the HttpError just fine. However, when calling the API from another server, All I get in return is an Net.Http.StreamContent. I can't seem to pull out the HTTPError for consumption.

```
 var response =  client.GetAsync(apiSignature).Result;


 // RETURN INSTANCE OF THE REQUESTED RESOURCE
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
    return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent 
    ? default(T)
    : response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
 }

  // DEAL WITH ERROR CASE
  var httpError = GetHttpError(response);
```

This will always return a null;

```
 protected HttpError GetHttpError(HttpResponseMessage message)
 {
    HttpError err;
    message.TryGetContentValue(out err);
    return err;
 }
```

I have full control over both code basis, so I am not married to the HTTP error, but I do like what it provides and would like to use it if possible.

Thanks again,

(MS Visual Studio Web API application, Window's Azure deployment, but testing locally)

SteveJ

Comment: Is you RESTAPI configured for Cross Origin Policy (CORS). Please check and let us know

Comment: @meetkichu, I swim in the shallow end of the API pool still, but it is configured however it comes out of the box - so to speak.